# Java Application Bundled for Mac doesn't start

Tags: java, macos, bundle

I'm using jarbundler 2.2.0 as suggested by other answers since the application should run on JRE 1.6 by Apple.

The bundle seems to be right, shows with the appropriate icon but clicking on it doesn't do anything. If I go into it's contents and try double clicking the jar with the main file specified works fine.

Is there a way to see what's happening? Some kind of error or log I can see?

**Edit**
Requested Info.plist. Since the code is private I replaced some stuff with Application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Application</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.2.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Application version</string>
    <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
    <string>false</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>JavaApplicationStub</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>beta</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>SynamicD.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw</string>
    <key>Java</key>
    <dict>
      <key>MainClass</key>
      <string>net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.Main</string>
      <key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.6.*</string>
      <key>ClassPath</key>
      <array>
        <string>$JAVAROOT/Application.jar</string>
        <string>$JAVAROOT/lib\lib1.jar</string>
        <string>$JAVAROOT/lib\lib2.jar</string>
      </array>
      <key>Properties</key>
      <dict>
        <key>apple.awt.textantialiasing</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>apple.awt.brushMetal</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>apple.awt.showGrowBox</key>
        <string>true</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Contents of PkgInfo:

```
APPL????
```

On the Application.app/Contents/MacOS I have the JavaApplicationStub from the Mac Machine.

Resulting file structure:

```
Application.app
|
---Contents
      |
      ---Info.plist
      ---PkgInfo
      ---MacOS
            |
      |      ---JavaApplicationStub
      ---Resources
            |
             ---Java
                  |
                   ----lib
                        |
                         ---lib1.jar
                        |
                         ---lib2.jar
                  |
                   ---Application.jar
            |
             ---Application.icns
```

Requested outputs to commands:

```
~ $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
~ $ sw_vers -productVersion
10.8.2
~ $ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.7.0_17, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_15, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_43-b01-447, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_43-b01-447, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home
~ $ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home
~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME

~ $ echo $JAVA_ARCH

~ $ /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
~ $ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
jdk1.7.0_15.jdk jdk1.7.0_17.jdk
~ $ /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/java -version
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01-447-11M4203)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01-447, mixed mode)
~ $
```

Comment: I don't know about the best way to make a bundle for Java, but a quick look at FreeMind (freemind.sourceforge.net) shows that they have a Java dir with the jar in Resources and a JavaApplicationStub link in it's Contents.

Comment: I have it that way as well.

Comment: What is the value of `CFBundleExecutable` in the bundle's Info.plist? It should be the name of the binary file in the MacOS folder.

Comment: Actually, it might be a good idea to post the Info.plist file here, so we can have a look.

Comment: Added all the details I could without giving away private information.

Comment: you can take a look at eclipse.app :)

Comment: @javydreamercsw Can you post the file structure of the .app directory?

Comment: See edited question with the requested outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those backslashes are certainly wrong, as Mac OS is Unix.  Should be:

```
  <array>
    <string>$JAVAROOT/Application.jar</string>
    <string>$JAVAROOT/lib/lib1.jar</string>
    <string>$JAVAROOT/lib/lib2.jar</string>
  </array>
```

Since you said you did this on Windows, another thing I would check is file permissions.  These files in particular:

- MacOS/JavaApplicationStub (rwxrwxr-x)
- Resources/Java/Application.jar (-rw-rw-r--)
- Resources/Java/lib/lib1.jar (-rw-rw-r--)
- Resources/Java/lib/lib2.jar (-rw-rw-r--)

And finally, the JVMVersion of 1.6* is [not recommended](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html).  Try using 1.5+ or 1.6+ instead, as it may be more compatible.

Ruling out all the above, the issue must lie with JavaApplicationStub.  Note, from the JarBundler pages:

> When the JarBundler ANT task is used under Windows or Linux, a copy of the JavaApplicationStub must be supplied by the developer. This cannot be built from source but must be obtained from a Mac OS X system.

**A Known problem with Java launching stub**

> In early 2006 an Apple upgrade to Quicktime (7.0.4) caused older
>   versions of "JavaApplicationStub" to fail to start up. These old
>   copies came from developers who first created the application bundle
>   as a directory and then created new applications by replacing the JAR
>   files within the bundle and not replacing "JavaApplicationStub" with a
>   more current copy.

Comment: Hmmmm. All that was done by the jarbundler. Maybe because I executed on Windows... I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @javydreamercsw Please see my revised answer.

Comment: When ran on Linux based OS the slashes are done correctly. I get the same result with the file permissions you mention. The app doesn't start but running the jar directly does.

Comment: @javydreamercsw I've recreated your file structure and Info.plist and everything works as expected.  Other than the backslashes, there is nothing wrong with what you posted.  I am still guessing the issue lies with file permissions or ownership.

Comment: @javydreamercsw Note that JavaApplicationStub is a Mac OS binary.  How is this binary formed when you are building on Windows or Linux?  Can you output 'ls -l' of JavaApplicationStub?

Comment: @javydreamercsw Please see my revised answer.

Comment: You are right it worked! It was working all along. For some reason it breaks when I tar the folder! The app starts but gets an error due run on Java 7, but that's another question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried launching your application via the terminal using `open`?

```
open Application.app
```

This should give you more information on why the application is failing to execute your jar.

Update:
Upon running through `open` yields:

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/MacBookPro/NetBeansProjects/SynamicD/dist/SynamicD.app

Referencing https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/LaunchServicesReference.pdf (page 69) shows that the error description is:

> kLSUnknownErr -10810 An unknown error has occurred. Available in OS X v10.0 and later.

Comment: This is what I get when I try: LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/MacBookPro/NetBeansProjects/SynamicD/dist/SynamicD.app.

Comment: Looks like that is "kLSUnknownErr -10810 An unknown error has occurred.
Available in OS X v10.0 and later." via page 69 of https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/LaunchServicesReference.pdf.  Not much help there.  Can you open Console.app and look for your apps name? There should be more information there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the answer, but I don't have Mac of my own and depend on others to develop/test.

Comment: Found nothing in the console.